# Pass a CGSize through performSelector

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a method that returns a CGSize like so...

```
-(CGSize)theSizeToUse
```

Then elsewhere I have code asking if the class responds to this selector, and if so, call it using perform selector...

```
if ([myClass respondsToSelector:@selector(theSizeToUse)])    CGSize
   theSize = [myClass performSelector:@selector:(theSizeToUse)];
```

Well, this isn't going to work because performSelector is going to return an id, not a CGSize, so I looked into wrapping it in an NSValue and returning an NSValue which I'd then unwrap.

Looking at the documentation for NSValue, it's very clear what to do... simply call `NSValue valueWithSize` to pack it, and `NSValue sizeValue` to unpack it.
All went well until I got to sizeValue... there is no such property or method.

I'm developing for iOS, targeting iOS 7 on a MacBook with OS X 10.10

Any idea how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably looked up `NSValue` via Google? That takes you to the Mac documentation, which suggests `+valueWithSize:` and `sizeValue` for `NSSize` structs. `NSSize` isn't defined on iOS.

For iOS you should use `+valueWithCGSize:` and `-CGSizeValue`. The iOS documentation for `NSValue` is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValue_Class/index.html).

Comment: Is it worth enquiring as to why you're using `performSelector:`? I've assumed it's because that's actually a parameter of some sort and not a direct `@selector` as per the code given. Otherwise you could just do `[myClass theSizeToUse]`. Also if you're investigating this are generally it might be helpful to read up on key-value coding and `valueForKey:` which is defined on `NSObject`. But you'll still be looking to pass around classes so it's not strictly relevant, just potentially interesting.

Comment: I have a generic factory method that returns various popover controls of varying sizes, and not all of my implmentations have `theSizeToUse` and since I'm not using a delegate either, this is the only way to guarantee that I don't blow anything up... using performSelector:

Comment: An idea here to avoid `performSelector` is to create and use a `@protocol` that implements that method. any class you need to have it just needs to use that protocol.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, that's what I meant by delegate... I used the wrong word.

Comment: Performing the `respondsToSelector:` test is enough to "avoid a doesn't respond to selector" exception; if it really is a fixed method name then you could just do `[myClass theSizeToUse]` within the `if` clause.